# Detect digits within character string of specific form in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a string like this:

```
TransID [12345, 67890]; Btool_ID [22222]; Reconsile [ccccc]; RequestID [ aaaaa];
```

I want to extract the string in TransID[], but when I use the code:

```
gsub(".*TransID \\[(.*)\\].*", "\\1", data)
```

It gave me:

```
12345, 67890]; Btool_ID [22222]; Reconsile [ccccc]; RequestID [ aaaaa
```

My desired output is:

```
"12345, 67890"
```

How could I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about,

```
sub('TransID \\[(\\d+, \\d+)\\].*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "12345, 67890"
```